# Why isEmpty not working here ?

Tags: swift

i made a structure here 
`struct dicStruct<T,U>{}`

anad here is my instance of its

`var instanceOfDicStruct:dicStruct<Int,String> = dicStruct()`

isEmpty is not working here can anyone explain of send me some reference ?

`instanceOfDicStruct.isEmpty`

Comment: Would = nil work

Comment: Yes Nil working But i need to know why isEmpty is not working just for interest .

Comment: You defined your own type `dicStruct` and that does not have a `isEmpty` method. Not sure what you expected.

Comment: Note that is is Swift convention to name your structures starting with an uppercase letter. You should take some time and read Apple Swift Book https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-4/id881256329?mt=11. What you are probably trying to achieve is `struct MyStruct {
   var instancePropertyOfMyStruct: [Int: String] = [:]
}
var instanceOfMyStruct = MyStruct()
instanceOfMyStruct.instancePropertyOfMyStruct.isEmpty`   // true

Comment: Wow you i am also big fan of Rush i am Musician too xD Btw i used swift convention still its not working ..i know what i am doing am new in swift i was just trying to learn the swift type Struct ..Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A struct with two generic placeholder types ≠ dictionary.

If you need a dictionary, then create an instance of a dictionary like so:

```
var dictionaryInstance = [Int: String]()
```

`isEmpty` works now:

```
print(dictionaryInstance.isEmpty) // true
```

You can also create a typealias:

```
typealias MyDictionary = [Int: String]

var myDictionaryInstance = MyDictionary()
```

Comment: Thank you ..i was just trying to learn the swift Dictionary And others Type Structure ..If you know any blog or book about it ..it will help me

Comment: @EkramulHoque Take some time and read the Apple's Swift Book. There is plenty os examples there about all Swift types including dictionaries and its is free  https://itunes.apple.com/br/book/the-swift-programming-language-swift-4/id881256329?l=en&mt=11